# AdMob (error code 3) only with my ID

Tags: android, admob, banner

I'm developing an app, AdMob ads used to work perfectly but they suddenly stopped working. They just won't show up.

So I analyzed the failure event, and I get error code 3. According to the docs, that means my code is right but the server is not returning the ads.

I'm not using yet the final banners, I'm using test units, and they don't work.

The point is I tried changing my app ID (package), from com.xxxx.xxx to anything else (I just removed any letter), and then ads work perfectly. Without changing a single line of code. I tried my code on other projects, and it works just fine. But with that specific ID, ads don't work.

So "perhaps AdMob blocked or banned my app?", that's what I thought, but I wrote a mail to AdMob support and they told me that my app isn't blocked or banned, and according to them, everything is alright with that ID.

UPDATE: not only on my phone. Ads don't show up on any device.

So, any idea?